# Windows update install hangs

Tags: windows-xp, .net

I'm trying to deploy .Net 3.5 on an XP home SP2 machine for a customer. The install fails, with an error about WIC. Trying to install WIC on its own gave an error about not being able to verify the application, because the cryptographic service wasn't running.

A reboot got that service running, but now the install just hangs on the "inspecting your current configuration"

Task manager reports that DrWatson is doing a lot (constantly using 10% of processor time) but beyond that I don't know how to instrument what a Windows machine is doing, has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

Please see if there are any Windows Installer Service errors reported in the Application/System event logs and post them here.

Comment: I looked in event log. According to the event log install of .Net 3.5 went successfully.

Customer has just bought a win7 license though so won't need to install. Can I close my own question?